# How to change the editor's background color with scintilla?

Tags: mfc, scintilla

How to change the editor's background color with scintilla, I don’t know scintilla very much, but it works really, and How?

Answer (score 2):

```
SendMessage(SCI_STYLESETBACK, STYLE_DEFAULT, RGB(0,0,0));
```

This code sets the default style's background to black.

Comment: but the background color of the text is still unchanged and it looks very strange,How can I change the text's background color at the same time, thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using a lexer, you will need to set the background color for each style. For example, if you are using the C lexer,  SendMessage(SCI_STYLESETBACK, SCE_C_DEFAULT, RGB(0,0,0))  and then the same for each style defined in the lexer.

Answer (score 1):

`SCI_STYLESETBACK` sets the background colour of the text. If it's not producing the results you're looking for please post a screenshot. Another setting that might help you is: `SCI_SETWHITESPACEBACK`?

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
SendMessage(SCI_STYLESETBACK, 32, (LPARAM)RGB(r, g, b));  // set back-color of window

SendMessage(SCI_STYLESETBACK, 33, (LPARAM)RGB(r, g, b));  // set back-color of margin
```